# Find $\int \limits_0^\pi \sin(\sin(x))\sin(x)\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Compute $\displaystyle \int \limits_0^\pi \sin(\sin(x))\sin(x)\mathrm dx$.

I have no idea how to integrate of this. I do need some help. Thanks

Comment: As a starting point, you should surely try testing what happens if you take the derivatives of the four functions $\sin\sin x$, $\sin\cos x$, $\cos\sin x$, and $\cos\cos x$ just to see what happens. That would be the very first think I thought of. Then maybe you can see something you might be able to do to "undo" the derivative, or perhaps make a clever substitution.

Comment: WolframAlpha doesn't have a solution for it (for the indefinite integral). Therefore, it probably doesn't exist. However, the answer is about $1.3824597$.

Comment: Try $\sin x = t$, and see what happends.

Comment: It's apparently equal to $\pi J_1(1)$ which is some "Bessel function." Google told me that it was defined by Bernoulli. I quit, I can't be Bernoulli anymore.

Comment: The function is symmetric about $\pi/2$, so the integral is the same as $2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\sin(x))\sin(x)\,dx$. From there, a $u$-substitution and integration by parts show it is equal to $2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(u)\sqrt{1-u^2}\,du$, if that helps.

Comment: @ImanolPérezArribas As with Ayesha's answer, since that substitution is not invertible on $[0,\pi]$, that is not as helpful as it may seem.

Comment: @alex.jordan Well, I mean after dividing the integral into two different integrals: $\displaystyle \int \limits_0^\pi/2 \sin(\sin(x))\sin(x)\mathrm dx + \displaystyle \int \limits_{\pi/2}^\pi \sin(\sin(x))\sin(x)\mathrm dx$

Comment: @ImanolPérezArribas so that just leads to $2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\sin(x))\sin(x)\, dx$: the same integrand over half the interval and then doubled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution using Taylor Series:

$$\sin(\sin x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(\sin x)^{2n+1}$$

$$\sin(\sin x) \sin x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(\sin x)^{2n+2}$$

$$\int_0^\pi \sin(\sin x) \sin x \, dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\int_0^\pi(\sin x)^{2n+2} dx$$

Note that $\int_0^\pi(\sin x)^{2n+2} dx = \pi \frac{(2n+1)(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 3 \cdot 1}{(2n+2)(2n)(2n-2)\cdots 4 \cdot 2} = \pi \frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}$ for any non-negative integer $n$. You can use the following reduction formula to prove it:

$$\int \sin^n x \, dx = - \frac{1}{n} \sin^{n-1} x \cos^{n-1} x + \frac{n-1}{n} \int \sin^{n-2} x \, dx$$

So we have:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi \sin(\sin x) \sin x \, dx &= \pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)} \frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!} \\
&= \pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!!(2n+2)!!} \\
&= \pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2^n n!) (2^{n+1} (n+1)!)} \\
&= \pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n+1} n! (n+1)!} \\
\end{align}$$

Now you can note that the summation here is exactly the definition of $J_1(1)$, where $J_\alpha(x)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

So $$\int_0^\pi \sin(\sin x) \sin x \, dx = \pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n+1} n! (n+1)!} = \pi J_1(1) \approx 1.38246$$

Comment: +1 : in fact, IIRC all the Fourier coefficients of $\sin(\sin(x))$ can be expressed via Bessel functions - I actually came across this at one point in some audio research(!) into feedback circuits (specifically, finding the tones that appear when the output of a (constant-frequency) sine-wave generator is patched into the frequency input of another sine-wave generator).

Comment: You guys are awsome. Thanks a lot, but how about if the equation is changed to ∫sin(Asin(x))sin(x)dx, A is constant?

Comment: Why sin(sinx) and sinx have the same representation of taylor series?

Comment: For ∫sin(Asin(x))sin(x)dx, you will end up with another factor of $A^{2n+1}$ in the summation, which you can see would give you $\pi J_1(A)$ rather than $\pi J_1(1)$. As for your second comment, $\sin x$ and $\sin (\sin x)$ do not have the same representation as Taylor series. Note that I substituted $\sin x$ in for $x$ in the Taylor series representation of $\sin x$ to get a series representing $\sin (\sin x)$ (this technically isn't a Taylor series, since it has powers of $\sin x$ rather than powers of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens when we try the substitution $u = \sin{x}$?

Comment: What does happen?

Comment: You end up with $2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u\sin u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du = \pi\cdot J_1(1),$ so the integral can be written in terms of a specific value of a Bessel function.

Comment: By writing $\sin(\sin x)$ as $\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^j (\sin x)^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}$ and integrating termwise, we get the pretty fast convergent series: $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(\sin x)\sin x\,dx = \pi\cdot J_1(1) = \pi\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!(j+1)!2^{2j+1}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of

$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(\cos(\sin(\cos( x)))) dx   $ where we iterate the expression in the integrand, replacing $x$ by $ \sin(\cos( x))  $ and  which goes to   $0.6948196907307875\ldots$ (a fixed point of  $\sin(\cos(x_0)) = x_0$).